# javascript/ function which sends userinfomation back from db & global variable

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the userdata from Firestore as a variable. With this code I get the error :

> ReferenceError: user1 is not defined

Is it possible to generate a function which looks in firebase for the `user.uid` and callback a variable with the infomations, so I can access the data via "`user1.username`"?

```
app.get('/site', function (req, res) {

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    // get userdata from db and set to variable
    db.collection("users").doc(user.uid)
    .get().then(function(doc) {
      if (doc.exists){
        // Convert to user object
        user1 = doc.data();
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!")
      }}).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error)
      });
res.render('site', { username: user1.username});
});
```

It's working when I put

```
res.render('site', { username: user1.username});
```

inside the `function(doc)`, but I'm sure there is a way to generate a function and calling the variables by adding the function at the start like...

```
("app.get('/site', getuserinfos, function (req, res)")
```

Comment: The database operation is *asynchronous*, so putting `res.render()` inside the `.then()` callback is the correct thing to do.

Comment: Thank you for your fast respond. I will work with your answer. Is there no simple way to put this into a function and get the infomations as a return variable?

Comment: That is a question asked *all the time* and the answer is basically "no".  There are facilities in modern JavaScript environments that make handling asynchronous APIs somewhat cleaner, but in the end you cannot make an asynchronous API behave as if it were synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any code that needs access to the data from the database, needs to be in the callback that is called when that data is available.

So:

```
app.get('/site', function (req, res) {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    db.collection("users").doc(user.uid)
    .get().then(function(doc) {
      if (doc.exists){
        user1 = doc.data();
        res.render('site', { username: user1.username});
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!")
        // TODO: send a response
      }}).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error)
        // TODO: send a response
      });
});
```

---

If you're struggling reading this code, you can make it a bit more familiar by using the `async` / `await`  keywords:

```
app.get('/site', async function (req, res) {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    let user1 = await db.collection("users").doc(user.uid)
      .get().then(function(doc) {
        if (doc.exists){
          return doc.data();
        } else {
          console.log("No such document!")
          // TODO: return something to render or throw an error
        }}).catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error getting document:", error)
          // TODO: send a response
        });
    res.render('site', { username: user1.username});
});
```

Or simpler:

```
app.get('/site', async function (req, res) {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    let doc = await db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).get();

    if (doc.exists){
      res.render('site', { username: doc.data().username});
    } else {
      console.log("No such document!")
      // TODO: send a response
    }}).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error)
      // TODO: send a response
    });
});
```

Just keep in mind that, while this code may read more familiar, it is still performing an asynchronous call to the database and you'll need to be aware of that.

Comment: If you are doing the first one I would recommend returning the promise ;-). The second the promise wrapping is implicit

Comment: @JGleason I added an example without bubbling up results, which I think is what you mean. If you have further improvements, I'd recommend posting them as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Frank van Puffelen's answer is fine because you probably are not using too much in the way of middleware.

However, I would make sure to return the promise like this...

```
app.get('/site', (req, res) => {
    return db.collection("users").doc(
        firebase?.auth()
            ?.currentUser
            ?.uid
    )
    .get()
    .then((doc) => doc.exists ?
            res.render(
                'site',
                {
                    username: doc.data().username
                }
            ) : console.log("No such document!")
            , (error) =>
                console.log( "Error getting document:", error )
    );
});
```

await would be similar

```
app.get('/site', async (req, res) => {
    return await db.collection("users").doc(
        firebase?.auth()
            ?.currentUser
            ?.uid
    )
    .get()
    .then((doc) => doc.exists ?
            res.render(
                'site',
                {
                    username: doc.data().username
                }
            ) : console.log("No such document!")
            , (error) =>
                console.log( "Error getting document:", error )
    );
});
```